# Insert dataset records in database

Tags: c#, ms-access, dataset

I need to insert the dataset records(C#) into the MS Accessdatabase table. I need to do the bulk insertion of records.

How can I do this in C#

Answer (score 5):

For this sort of task, consider using the [data adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbdataadapter.aspx) abstraction. With an Microsoft Access database, you can use the [`OleDbDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.aspx) implementation as shown in the example below:

```
// Prerequisite: The data to be inserted is available in a DataTable/DataSet.
var data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add("CompanyName", typeof(string));
data.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(string));
data.Rows.Add("Foo", "12345678");
data.Rows.Add("Bar", "87654321");

// Now, open a database connection using the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB provider.
// The "using" statement ensures that the connection is closed no matter what.
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=Northwind.mdb"))
{
    connection.Open();

    // Create an OleDbDataAdapter and provide it with an INSERT command.
    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Shippers (CompanyName, Phone) VALUES (@CompanyName , @Phone)", connection);
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("CompanyName", OleDbType.VarChar, 40, "CompanyName");
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Phone", OleDbType.VarChar, 24, "Phone");

    // Hit the big red button!
    adapter.Update(data);
}
```

You can do the same against other brands of database engines as well by replacing `OleDbCommand`, `OleDbDataAdapter` and `OleDbConnection` with the appropriate implementations for your database engine. For Microsoft SQL Server, look for classes prefixed with `Sql`, eg. [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
   public void insert_dataset(DataSet ds,string ret_table, string table, string fileds, ArrayList arr_data)
    {
        ArrayList arr_rec=new ArrayList();

        string[] str_fields = fileds.Split(',');

        for (int i=0;i<ds.Tables[ret_table].Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < str_fields.Length; j++)
            {
                arr_rec.Add(ds.Tables[ret_table].Rows[i].ItemArray[j]);
            }

            insert_table(table, fileds, arr_rec);

            arr_rec.Clear();
        }


    }
    public void insert_table(string table,string fileds,ArrayList arr_data)
    {
        string str_command, str_params;

        string[] str_fields = fileds.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < str_fields.Length; i++)
        {
            str_fields[i] = "@" + str_fields[i].Trim();
        }

        str_params = string.Join(",", str_fields);

        str_command = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(" + fileds + ") values(" + str_params + ")";

        con = new OleDbConnection();
        //for sql
        //con=new SqlConnection();

        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + frm_main.cur_directory + "\\db_temp1.mdb;Persist Security Info=True";
        //for sql
        //con.ConnectionString="server=(local);trusted_connection=yes;database=telephon;";

        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        //for sql
        //cmd=new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();

        cmd.CommandText =str_command;

       // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACagname", "2");
       for (int i = 0; i < arr_data.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(str_fields[i],arr_data[i]);
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add some information to your code snipped.